# Logarithmic growth counter

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mathematics

I'm looking for a way to have an logarithmic incremental counter. The counter goal is related to a numeric value than goes from 1 to Infinity. The counter maximum value should be 1000. 
The sequence looks like this:

- number is below 10, increment by 1:

  1,2,3...7,8,9,10
- number is above 10, increment by ^10 when the number reaches the counter

  100, 1000 stop at 1000

This is what I wrote so far (javascript):

```js
let i = 0
let mod = 10
let result = document.getElementById('result')
result.innerText = ''

while (++i < 7322) {
  mod *= mod < 1000 && i === mod * 10 ? 10 : 1

  if (i < 10 || i % mod === 0) {
    //the further the `i` value is, the less this will be called
    result.innerText += i + ' pass the test. Mod is ' + mod + '.\n'
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way of doing this but can't get my hand on it. Do you have ideas on how to simplify the algorithm?

Comment: Are you looking for elegance in providing values for `i` or `mod`?

Comment: For `mod`, `i` is just a random number

Comment: (The repetition of `10-`in the title is distracting: can you explain or remove it?)

Comment: Done, I kinda had a hard time trying to explain. Finding a good title was even harder...

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is a bit wasteful by generating and testing all integers in the desired range while you actually only need a handful of them.

A big improvement in terms of performance is to avoid modulo arithmetic and increase the step-size tenfold whenever you finished iterating a sub-range 1-9, 10-99, 100-999 and so on:

```js
let max = 7322;
let step = 1;
let next = 10;

while (step < 1000 && next < max) {
  for (let i = step; i < next; i += step) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  step = next;
  next *= 10;
}

for (let i = step; i < max; i += step) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Of course, you might want to encapsulate above code in a function or even more versatile, a generator function and replace `console.log(i);` with `yield i;`.

However, since you only have four different step-sizes of 1, 10, 100, and 1000 you can encode them manually and come up with an even simpler generator function as follows:

```js
// Generate logarithmic range from 1 to max (excluded):
function* logRange(max) {
  for (let i = 1; i < max && i < 10; i += 1) yield i;
  for (let i = 10; i < max && i < 100; i += 10) yield i;
  for (let i = 100; i < max && i < 1000; i += 100) yield i;
  for (let i = 1000; i < max; i += 1000) yield i;
}

// Example:
for (let i of logRange(7322)) console.log(i);
```

This avoids modulo arithmetic, computes only the desired numbers and is pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your changes of `mod` coincide with the condition of "the `if`":

```
mod = 1;
while (++i < 12345) {
    if (i % mod === 0) {
        //the further the `i` value is, the less this will be called
        result.innerText += i + ' pass the test. Mod is ' + mod + '.\n'
        if (mod < 1000 && i === mod * 10)
            mod = i
  }
}
```

(Can't seem to get the snippets to work in firefox 50.1?!)